# Рекурсивный вывод данных из многомерного массива php

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Есть массив с позициями в организации:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => 
            [position-ru] => Старший специалист
            [description] => ...
            [next] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [position] => 
                            [position-ru] => Эксперт
                            [description] => ...
                            [next] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [position] => 
                                            [position-ru] => Ведущий эксперт
                                            [description] => ...
                                            [next] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [position] => 
                                                            [position-ru] => Руководитель
                                                            [description] => ...
                                                            [next] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [position] => 
                                                                            [position-ru] => Директор
                                                                            [description] => ...
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [position] => 
                                            [position-ru] => Менеджер
                                            [description] => ...
                                            [next] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [position] => 
                                                            [position-ru] => Руководитель
                                                            [description] => ...
                                                            [next] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [position] => 
                                                                            [position-ru] => Директор
                                                                            [description] => ...
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [position] => 
                                            [position-ru] => Руководитель группы
                                            [description] => ...
                                            [next] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [position] => 
                                                            [position-ru] => Руководитель
                                                            [description] => ...
                                                            [next] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [position] => 
                                                                            [position-ru] => Директор
                                                                            [description] => ...
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Нужно вывести все варианты путей от Старшего специалиста до Руководителя, в виде такого массива:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Старший специалист
            [1] => Эксперт
            [2] => Ведущий эксперт
            [3] => Руководитель
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Старший специалист
            [1] => Эксперт
            [2] => Менеджер
            [3] => Руководитель
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Старший специалист
            [1] => Эксперт
            [2] => Руководитель группы
            [3] => Руководитель
        )

)
```

Мой код:

```
$b = 'Руководитель';

function rez($data, $b, &$result, $t = 0)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $pos = $data[$k]['position-ru'];
        $next = $data[$k]['next'];
        $result[$t][] = $pos;
        if ($pos !== $b && !empty($next)) {
            $data_ = $data;
            $data = $next;
            rez($data, $b, $result, $t);
            $data = $data_;
        }
        $t++;
    }
}
```

Выводит следующее:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Старший специалист
            [1] => Эксперт
            [2] => Ведущий эксперт
            [3] => Руководитель
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Менеджер
            [1] => Руководитель
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Руководитель группы
            [1] => Руководитель
        )

)
```

Как можно доработать код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function directions($arr, $b, &$result, $path = null)
{
    $pos = $arr['position-ru'];
    $next = $arr['next'];
    unset($arr['next']);
    $path[] = $arr;

    if ($pos == $b) {
        $result[] = $path;
    } elseif (!empty($next)) {
        foreach ($next as $k) {
            directions($k, $b, $result, $path);
        }
    }
}
```